# always grouped product (simple product associated, grouped product associated)

Tags: grouped-products

A lot of the products are grouped products, with grouped products associated.
Don't know how this is possible, if he worked via database.

In the website version the products are showing up in the frontend, but in my copy of the site, after the reindex process and after cleaning the cache, the products disappeared.

Another thing, i added a new attribute to my products, but this don't seems to be the problem.

How can i always show grouped product in the frontend, with or without associated products?

Answer (score 0):

Groupped products are really not displayed if they have no associated products. And I think it's because Price Index, because Grouped products have no their own price and get Price from associated products.

To be sure - you can copy data from "catalog_product_index_price" database table (from production server to your local copy).

If it will work, then you can just turn Price Index (at Admin - System - Index Management) to Manual Update mode and just not touch it in the future.

But actually you will not be able to buy products if one grouped product is associated to another. Because products will just have no prices

Comment: You're welcome! karma + ? ^.^